# Spivak's Calculus Chapter 11 exercise 30 solution verification

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, parametric, classical-mechanics

I'm confused about the following problem. Calculus by Spivak, 3rd Edition, Chapter 11, exercise 30:

> A cannon ball is shot from the ground with velocity $v$ at and angle $\alpha$ (Figure 31) so that it has a vertical component of velocity $v\sin\alpha$ and a horizontal component $v\cos\alpha$. Its distance $s(t)$ above the ground obeys the law $s(t) = -16t^2 + (v\sin\alpha)t$, while its horizontal velocity remains constantly $v\cos\alpha$.

[image: Figure 31]

> (a) Show that the path of the cannon ball is a parabola (find the position at each time $t$ and show that these points lie on a parabola).

So, we have
$$x^\prime(t)= v\cos\alpha$$
$$x(t) = (v\cos\alpha)t + c$$

Assuming $x(0) = 0$, we have

$$x(t) = (v\cos\alpha)t$$

Now, if $\cos\alpha \neq 0$, we can write:
$$t = \frac{x}{v\cos\alpha}$$

Per the text, the vertical position of the cannon ball is given by:
$$y(t) = -16t^2 + (v\sin\alpha)t$$

Substituting $\frac{x}{v\cos\alpha}$ in for $t$ we get:

$$y =  -16\left(\frac{x}{v\cos\alpha}\right)^2 + (v\sin\alpha)\left(\frac{x}{v\cos\alpha}\right)$$
$$y = \frac{-16x^2}{v^2\cos^2\alpha} + (\tan\alpha)x$$

For $\cos\alpha \neq 0$, this is the equation of a parabola.

However, this differs from Spivak's solution:

> 30. (a) The position at time $t$ is
>     $$((v\cos\alpha)t, -16t^2 + (v\sin\alpha)t).$$
>     If $\cos\alpha = 0$, so that the cannon ball is shot straight up, then these points all lie on a straight line. If $\cos\alpha \neq 0$, then the set of all such points is equal to the set of all points
>     $$\left(t, -\frac{16t^2}{v\cos\alpha} + (\tan\alpha)t\right),$$
>     so the path of the cannon ball lies on the graph of
>     $$f(x) = \frac{-16x^2}{v\cos\alpha} + (\tan\alpha)x,$$
>     which is the graph of a parabola.

Notice that my equation for $y$ in terms of $x$ differs from Spivak's:
$$\frac{-16x^2}{v^2\cos^2\alpha} + (\tan\alpha)x \neq \frac{-16x^2}{v\cos\alpha} + (\tan\alpha)x$$

I think maybe he made a mistake going from here:
$$((v\cos\alpha)t, -16t^2 + (v\sin\alpha)t)$$
to here:
$$\left(t, -\frac{16t^2}{v\cos\alpha} + (\tan\alpha)t\right)$$

He multiplies the $x$ and $y$ coordinates by $\frac{1}{v\cos\alpha}$.
This is incorrect, right?

For example, if you have:

$$f(x) = x^2$$

this would correspond with the points $(x, x^2)$, and includes the point $(a,a^2)$. This is not the same as the function associated with $(ax, ax^2)$ ($a \neq 0$), which includes the point $(a,a)$.

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct. It would be great if you could contact Michael Spivak to tell him you found a mistake.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks. This isn't the only mistake I've found (I think). I'm keeping a list of them, though to be fair, this isn't the most recent edition and many or all of these errors might be known already.